# Query de postgresql no funciona correctamente al agregar "where"

Tags: postgresql

Buen dia. Soy principiante en postgresql y estoy intentando generar un query para un reporte donde se cuenta el total de dispositivos en "A" y muestra quien es el dueño, en columna "B" se cuenta el total de dispositivos y quien es el dueño "C".
Cuando ejecuto el query me muestra los datos de forma correcta, el problema radica cuando filtró los dispositivos activos con un WHERE.

Ejemplo - la columna A tiene 10 registros y la B tiene 5 registros, cuando se ejecuta el query agregando el WHERE solo muestra 5 registros tanto en "A" como en "B", de no agregar el WHERE me agrega datos que ya no están activos. Parece que al agregar WHERE ignora el "Full outer join". Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

```
SELECT
count (distinct "A") AS "Arrays",
count (distinct "B") as "Appliances",
"C"."Description" as "Account"
FROM "C"
inner join "A"
on "A" = "C"."Id"
full outer join "B"
on "B" = "C"."Id"
WHERE "A"."Status" is = 'A'
group by "C"
```

Ejemplo ejecutando el Query sin "WHERE "A"."Status" is = 'A'", la consulta me muestra la información de forma correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo ejecutando el Query añadiendo "WHERE "A"."Status" is = 'A'", la condición es para que muestre solo aquellos dispositivos que están activos en la DB para descartar los inactivos de la columna "Appliances", solo que al hacerlo ya no muestra todos los registros de la columna "Arrays", se limita a solo mostrar los registros de la columna B.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, añade a tu pregunta algunos datos de prueba y la salida esperada con tu consulta. Es difícil saber qué quieres (y lo que falla) sólo viendo una consulta. Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/429610/edit) tu pregunta todas las veces que necesites, para añadir información

Comment: @Alfabravo, soy novato pero creo que el query y el ejemplo es claro, he posteado esta pregunta en otro lado y me entendieron sin problema. Intentare agregar alguna tabla como referencia.

Comment: Lamento no ser como los del otro lado. Por otra parte, acá a todos nos corresponde ofrecer un ejemplo mínimo verificable para que los demás nos puedan ayudar de forma oportuna y pues, el query es claro pero lo que buscas y el problema con tu query, no lo es.

Comment: @Alfabravo, disculpa a veces lo que es obvio para unos puede no ser para otros, mil disculpas. Agregue imágenes de los datos esperando que quede un poco más claro lo que trato de explicar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, el lío sería la forma en que lo filtras. Como estás exigiendo que HAYA un registro en A coincidente (el inner join) y la condición es que el A.status sea A, va a ignorar los casos nulos (esos en los que hay registro en B y C pero no en A).

Si en el SELECT hicieras algo como

```
SELECT
count (distinct "A") AS "Arrays",
count (distinct "B") as "Appliances",
"C"."Description" as "Account",
"A"."Status" as "Estado"
FROM "C"
INNER JOIN "A" on "A" = "C"."Id"
FULL OUTER JOIN "B" on "B" = "C"."Id"
GROUP BY "C"
```

Posiblemente (estoy adivinando porque ni idea que habrá en tus tablas; ves a qué me refiero?) verías que hay registros con status `A`, otros con el valor que sea que tienen los no activos (`I`?), y que habría registros con el Status nulo.

Así pues, podrías ver si algo como

```
SELECT
count (distinct "A") AS "Arrays",
count (distinct "B") as "Appliances",
"C"."Description" as "Account"
FROM "C"
INNER JOIN "A" on "A" = "C"."Id"
FULL OUTER JOIN "B" on "B" = "C"."Id"
WHERE ("A"."Status" = 'A' OR "A"."Status" is null)
GROUP BY "C"
```

te sirve.

Comment: gracias amigo si funciono. Me llama la atención que al agregar AND "B"."Status" = 'A' después del null para filtrar esos registros, lo ignora por completo, pero si lo filtró por una columna de la misma tabla donde está otro tipo de campo "B". "DeviceStatus" me filtra ambos campos de status los cuales no están relacionados, pero bueno! ya funciona que es lo importante. Muchas gracias por tu paciencia y ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: @ecorona depende de cómo lo pongas porque depende de la precedencia de los operadores lógicos. Procura usar paréntesis para definir en qué orden quieres que se resuelvan. Me alegra poder ser de ayuda.